# TextView always showing value as "0" on UI

Tags: android, textview

I am using a simple TextView and updating its value in onPostExecute of a AsyncTask. But every time its showing "0" on UI.

My code is:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
tv.setText(calculation());


private int calculation(){
return output;
}
```

What is going wrong here, no error comming in stack trace? please help me?

Comment: have you checked your calculation(); method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code `tv.setText(calculation());` tryind to take string from Resourses cause you set value as int.

Use `tv.setText(String.valueOf(calculation()));`

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
tv.setText(calculation()+"");
```

As TextView only accept string in settext, Adding +"" to int will make it as string.
and make sure that your method is returning the right value.

Comment: @selvin deleted.. now +1.? ;)

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271810/is-it-ok-to-ask-to-upvote-accept-my-own-answers#answer-271815

Comment: While a valid approach, this creates unnecessary garbage for the system. It creates three strings - the Integer.toString() of calculation(), the "" literal and the result which concatenates both. It's a better idea to use Integer.toString() or String.valueOf(int)