# android app .error on button when click it add number like ++

Tags: android

iam trying to make a button when click it add number like ++

i got an error while playing app

please help me to know why i got error

my code is like that

```
package com.m3taz.My_Counter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    public int myNum = 0;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        final TextView counterNum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counterNum);
        Button counterBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.counterBtn);

        counterBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                counterNum.setText(myNum++);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [TextView always showing value as "0" on UI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27226834/textview-always-showing-value-as-0-on-ui)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way

```
counterNum.setText(String.valueOf(myNum++));
```

You need to convert int value to string.

Answer (score 1):

When you need to **setText()** as **int** then you have cast int value to **String** otherwise find such **resource** which id is **int** value and given no such **resource** id found exception.

Example :

```
setText(String.valueOf((myNum++)))
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
counterNum.setText(""+myNum++);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @ChathurangaChandrasekara - How is this "not an answer to the question"??? This is clearly an attempt to answer. If you think the post is of low quality and needs moderator attention then use the flag link under the post.

Comment: @MoradiyaAkash because the question is asking why it's happening, it may be helpful for you to point out that `setText` is expecting a String, so you have to implicitly cast as a String.

Answer (score 0):

```
public final void setText (CharSequence text);
```

Sets the string value of the TextView. TextView does not accept integers.

I suggest you to ake a look at [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence))